# How to share single critical section between two classes

Tags: c++, critical-section

I have some trouble finding the right design solution for a problem of sharing same critical section object between two classes in different class hierarchies.

**Imagine:**

```
class IB;
class IA { 
    public: void method_one(); 
};
class A : public IA { 
    IB* m_ib; 
};

class IB { 
    public: void method_two(); 
};
class B : public IB { 
    IA* m_ia; 
};
```

Now, the calls to method_one() and method_two() should be synchronized. I happen to use critical_section object for synchronization, but wonder how should I do it.

I managed to figure out some ideas:

1. **BAD** - create suitable member (`critical_section m_cs;`) of either A or B, and
   a) downcast from IA to A (or from IB to B respectively), and use it
   b) make it static, and call `A::m_cs` (or `B::m_cs`)
2. **BETTER** - create additional singletonish object/struct that would manage critical_section object and provide an access to it:

   ```
   class CriticalSectionProvider {
       //(...)
   public: 
       static critical_section& GetIt() { static critical_section cs; return cs; }
   }
   ```

Unfortunately, I am not happy with any of these and think that someone may have better idea.

**How to share single critical section between two classes in this case?**

Comment: Extract the *protected resource* out to its own object, and place the critsect there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach is : create an instance of `critical_section` in the main(), before creating any threads between which you want to share the object.

Pass it to the constructors of the classes and store it as *reference*:

```
class A : public IA { 
    IB* m_ib; 
    critical_section & m_cs; //reference
    public:
           A(critical_section & cs) : m_cs(cs) {}
};

class B : public IB { 
    IA* m_ia; 
    critical_section & m_cs; //reference
    public:
           B(critical_section & cs) : m_cs(cs) {}
};

int main()
{
    critical_section cs = /*create it*/;

    A a = cs; //call the constructor, passing the reference
    B b = cs; //call the constructor, passing the reference
}
```